# How to use classes from the .jar lib added to netbeans project?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jar, package

Can anybody help me out in this?
what I have is a abc.jar file with me. It contains ABC.class file inside it. I added the jar file to netbeans project Libraries. But I am getting an error when I write
ABC a=new ABC();

Error :
"can not find symbol class ABC"

any help?

Edited :
also I am able to see the structure of ABC class when I click on the ABC.class file inside the  library.

Comment: Are the package declarations in synch?

Comment: Yes the package declarations are in sync. I am not able to figure out the problem.. This works fine in eclipse

Comment: I'm having the exact problem... I need to use classes inside a .jar file. These classes are not inside any named package. When I expand the .jar file, the classes reside in `<default package>`. There is thus no way to use an `import` statement. Running from the command-line works perfectly, however.

Comment: yes correct. You have to tell the .jar owner to pack classes inside different package than the default one. There is no other way round. I tried all sorts of things. nothing worked out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer :
I found out that if the jar has only default package you won't be able to import classes inside it. You need to have packages other than default inside the jar to import it. You can only import non default packages.
the thing with default packages works fins in eclipse, but not in netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to import it with an import statement. You should probably read the documentation that follows the jar file. Hopefully there's an example of usage - mostly there is.

Comment: yeah I am doing import correctly. But the thing I am doubtful is that ABC.class is in a default package inside ABC.jar. Is that the problem?
This thing works fine in eclipse, why not netbeans?

Comment: @tejas "*default package*"? If `ABC` were in the default package you could not import it. What's the import statement you are using?

Comment: when I clicked on the ABC.jar added to the libraries I saw a <default package> and ABC.class was listed inside it.

Comment: So is it the mistake of the person who sent it to me?
i tried with : import ABC.ABC; but it didn't work.
For using ABC.class in my code, does the sender need to place it in some named package?

Comment: @Mads : the jar is sent to me by the colleague, who is working on the other component of the project which I am supposed to use. There is no documentation for that.

Comment: I found out that if the jar has only default package you won't be able to import classes inside it.